# Get A 3D coordinates of a point from images and a Fundamental matrix

Tags: 3d, projective-geometry, projective-space

I have two photos of the same scene, taken from different places. I also have pairs of matching 2D points, which correspond to a same 3D point.

I found a fundamental matrix $F$ and epipoles $\textbf{e}, \textbf{e'}$.

```
F = 3.248066811936e-7, -0.000001956055020665,  -0.001234916325071597;
   -0.000004377971254,  8.358233379722482e-7,   0.019146763431467432;
    0.000165564399727, -0.017625490920276023,   1.000000000000000000
```

I computed camera matrices $P$ and $P'$ according to [the bottom of page 256](https://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/hzbook/hzbook2/HZepipolar.pdf).

$P=[I \mid \textbf{0} ], \\ P' = [[\textbf{e'}]_\times F + \textbf{e'}\textbf{v}^T \mid \lambda \textbf{e'}]$

I used $\textbf{v}=(0,0,0)^T$ and $\lambda=1$.

Some 3D point is at a pixel (395,128) in a first image, and at a pixel (530,108) in a second image. How can I find 3D coordinates of such point?

I see, that there are many degrees of freedom. I see, that $\lambda$ controls the distance between cameras, and the scale of the whole world. But what does the vector $v$ correspond to?

Comment: Please make your question self-contained instead of forcing people to chase external links to understand what you’re asking. While it’s good to link to the book that you’re using for full context, you should define any symbols that you’re using within the question itself.

Comment: Ok, I fixed it.

Comment: This is a great question, I wish there was an answer :(